# List all actors’ first and last names and their roles which start with the letter ‘P’

Tags: sql

List all actors’ first and last names and their roles which start with the letter ‘P’.

I've tried doing this but im not sure exactly why its not working.

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, r.role
FROM actors a
WHERE first_name, last_name, role like ‘P’
```

Comment: Please show us sample data for the `actor` and the `role` table.

Comment: Hint 1: `actors JOIN roles`.

Comment: Hint 2: `name like 'P%'`.

Comment: Please do a little study of the language before asking questions like this.  This is SQL101.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to *join* actors and roles.

Assuming structures like:

```
actors(id, first_name, last_name)
roles(role_id, actor_id, role)
```

Query:

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, r.role
from actors a
inner join roles r on a.id = r.actor_id and r.role like 'P%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one table with the following structure

```
---------
actors
---------
id
first_name
last_name
role
---------
```

you can use the following code

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, role
FROM actors
WHERE role like "p%"
```

if you want to use alias then

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.role
FROM actors AS a
WHERE role like "p%"
```

Answer (score -1):

retrieve the first and last name of actors and their associated awards including two actors who have ever seen their last and start with the letter is using right join between actors and actors award tables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post SQL demonstrating what you are describing?